# match/modify strings using python and re package

Tags: python, regex

Consider the following:

```py
sentences = list(
            'Y.M.C.A.',
            'HELLO WORLD',
            'We ARE the Best KIDS', 
            'from A.C.M. we PRESENT', 
            'Y9C1'
           )
```

How can I use python and re to output this?:

```
>>> Y.M.C.A
>>> Hello world
>>> We are the best kids
>>> From A.C.M. we present 
>>> Y.9.C.1
```

I've fiddled a bit, here is what I have so far:

```
for i in sentences:
    if re.match('([A-Z]|[0-9]?)+', i): # Matches list[0] and list[4]
        i.replace(' ', '.')
    elif re.match('What to put here?', i): # Should match list[3]
        i.title()
    else: 
        i.capitalize()
print(i)
```

I'm looking to differentiate the strings according to their capitalization and punctuation use, so far I've managed to match `Y.M.C.A.` and `Y.9.C.1`, but I cannot wrap my head around the last one.

According to [regexr/3lkus](https://regexr.com/3lkus) where I've tried this, I notice that my first if match also could've matched `from A.C.M. we PRESENT` as well.

I'm a bit confused as to how re.match and regex works behind the scenes here, could anyone shed a light on this?

**Edit**: I've made a change to how `list[3]` can be sentence cased as per comment by [Jean-François](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%c3%a7ois-fabre)

Comment: for starters try `'from A.C.M. we PRESENT'.title()`

Comment: If you just wanted to match capital letters that aren't: 1. at the start of the string; or 2. followed by a full stop, you could use `(?<!^)[A-Z](?!\.)`, then use `re.sub` to lowercase those matches. But your logic seems more complex than that, I'm not sure regex is a great idea for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there a string method to capitalize acronyms in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479043/is-there-a-string-method-to-capitalize-acronyms-in-python). I tried your code with that code and it does what you want.

Comment: how this string `O1A2 text IEFF text 1A` should be treated?

Comment: I'd recommend not overwriting the internal `list` type. It would be better to call your `list` something else like `words` or `sentences` or something.

Comment: @SomeGuyOnAComputer , I've made the change to have my example conform. Also, I don't see how this is a duplicate of that link you provided. It doesn't answer how I can match the strings properly.